# Using HTML5 pushstate on angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement html5's pushstate instead of the # navigation used by Angularjs. I have tried searching google for an answer and also tried the angular irc chat room with no luck yet.

This is my `controllers.js`:

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.phones = data;
    });
}

function PhoneDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
}

function greetCntr($scope, $window) {
    $scope.greet = function() {
    $("#modal").slideDown();
    }
}
```

app.js

```
angular.module('phoneapp', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/phones', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
                controller: PhoneListCtrl
            }).
            when('/phones/:phoneId', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
                controller: PhoneDetailCtrl
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/phones'
            });
    }])
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Inject $locationProvider into your config, and set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$locationProvider

Simple example:

JS:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page1', { template: 'page1.html', controller: 'Page1Ctrl' })
    .when('/page2', { template: 'page2.html', controller: 'Page2Ctrl' })
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/page1">Page 1</a> | <a href="/page2">Page 2</a>
```

Comment: Could I see a code sample for this when there's already config() for routeProvider? Not sure if I'm supposed to be creating a new config() for this or adding it to the first as an array of configs, and also not sure what the configFn should be (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module)

Comment: I have done the same but when i click /phones/:phoneId the template  url become phones/partials/phone-detail.html and firebug net tab shows html page not found

Comment: I am also getting page not found whenever I navigate to a given url in the browser (e.g. `/home` instead of `/`). Have you tried enabling html5 for your own site?

Comment: You have to configure your server to allow you to pull pages correctly.
When you try to navigate to `mysite.com/hello`, it is trying to GET that page from your server.  Instead, you want the browser to GET  `mysite.com` and then use angular to find the browser's location is `/hello` and go there.  So you need to configure your server to give back the `mysite.com` data no matter which subdomain is entered.

Comment: @AndyJoslin If the server is serving a REST API, how do you suggest it's configured?

Comment: I'd say put your rest API at `/api` or something, and then make everything but /api/* give out the index.html.

Comment: Bump for Andy Joslin's ridiculously thorough followup.

Comment: why use a bare html link instead of pushstate?  then you wouldn't have to worry about setting up handling on the server.  The only reason I could think of is to support IE < 10.

Comment: Does this fall back on the hash if the browser does not support pushstate?

Comment: This works if linking after initial index.html is loaded.  But if a derived link ie then accessed directly it results in 404.  How would one work around that?

Comment: "When you try to navigate to mysite.com/hello, it is trying to GET that page from your server. Instead, you want the browser to GET mysite.com and then use angular to find the browser's location is /hello and go there" - @AndyJoslin, won't delivering pages using this method block noscript users and robots? In the case of Google I guess http://goo.gl/flPXse, but it's a hassle...

Comment: @AndyJoslin I tried out your suggestion.  However, in my case, after returning `mysite.com/hello` the index.html, the various scripts/css in index.html starts to get requested with base url `mysite.com/hello` as opposed to `mysite.com/`.  The actual scripts/css are at `mysites.com/js/` and not `mysites.com/hello/js/`.  Is there a way in Angular.js to circumnavigate this problem?

Comment: @AndyJoslin Should one try using `.htaccess` rewrites in order to always point to the desired location (of the server)? Ir is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a way to do so with static pages and not on a server?

Comment: @Luke Yes, link your resources like this: `<script src="/js/some.js">` instead of `<script src="js/some.js">`, the initial slash makes it always look up starting from the root path of the website, instead of relative to the current directory.