# Apache rewrite rules not being applied for angularjs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup apache 2.2 with AngularJS with an almost exact structure as the one from the following closed question.

[rewrite rules for apache 2 to use with angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284038/rewrite-rules-for-apache-2-to-use-with-angular-js)

I would like to redirect all requests to app/index.html except for requests to /api.

My directory structure is as followed

- /
- /app
- /app/index.html
- /app/css
- /app/js
- /api

I am trying to apply these redirect rules in the httpd-vhosts file as such which was posted as the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284848/671095 to the question.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.test.com
DocumentRoot "C:/websites/test"
Alias /CFIDE "C:/websites/CFIDE"

RewriteEngine On

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api

# otherwise forward it to index.html 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^app/. /app/index.html [NC,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

However when I try visit / in the browser I am presented with a blank screen. If I enter to /app/index.html in the browser however I am able to view the html page in my browser but none of the css.or js can be accessed and is returning a 404.

I have been going nuts over this which seems like a simple thing to accomplish as an apache rewrite.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 15):

This is now much easier in Apache 2.2.16+ using the FallbackResource directive.

```
FallbackResource /app/index.html
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Depending on how you're forwarding access to your API you may need to also leverage the  enclosure to disable the fallback resource on specifically on API requests (2.2.24+).

```
<Directory /api>
    FallbackResource disabled
</Directory>
```

Comment: Works like a charm with apache 2.4.x !

Answer (score 11):

[This](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/) works for me:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Just to add to this comment, if your Angular app is not located at the root of the host, i.e. contents live in a directory like http://example.com/moo/, you need to add the appropriate `<base>` tag.

For the example of http://example.com/moo/, your tag needs to be `<base href="/moo/">` - this is so your assets and templates load correctly

Comment: @BahamutWC: Use of the base tag is discouraged; http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: @Daan it is only discouraged as far as Angular recommends that you serve it from the root document.  However if you cannot for whatever reason, you must use the `<base>` tag.

Comment: I kept getting Bad Request using this method. What fixed it was putting a slash in front of the index.html like so `RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L]`

Comment: This one was perfect for me, as front-end (angular) is index.html and subfolder/ is a backend laravel index.php, so defining index.`html` made it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. But I'm ignorant in `mod_rewrite` so had to Google a lot.
I found the solution in this email:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/GmNiNVyvonk/mmffPbIcnRoJ

So I think your .htaccess should look as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# otherwise forward it to index.html 
RewriteRule ^app/(.*) /app/#/$1 [NC,L]
```

Notice the `(.*)` and the `#/$1`

Note: you MUST use absolute paths in your includes CSS, JS, etc. if not you are going to get the error:

> resource interpreted as script but transferred with mime type text/html

Comment: I have applied these rules to httpd-vhosts file but when I try to access `mywebsite.com` it does not pass through to the index.html file also now when I access `mywebsite.com/app/` I am presented with a 404 in the browser

Comment: I used your code and I see the "Internal Server Error" message. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are still having this problem, but I was having the same symptoms with AngularJS and Apache 2.

My problem was actually that I was using IE and it was automatically coming up in compatability mode.  I used the line below in my HTML and it worked.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Described further here: < [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e) >.