# Still getting 'Not Found' when manually refreshing with angular.js route

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, angularjs, angular-routing

After reading a ton of write-ups and stackoverflow questions on Angular.js route, I'm still getting the 'Not Found' error when I do a manual refresh.

Steps:

1. browse to `localhost` --> because of my configuration (below), I'm taken to `localhost/home`. Views and everything load fine.
2. hit refresh in the browser --> browser displays this `Not Found: the requested /home is not found on this server`

This question is probably most like [Refreshing page gives "Page not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168836/refreshing-page-gives-page-not-found)

**My configuration**

```js
// Routing configuration.
angular.module('myModule')
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        // Enable pushState in routes.
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templates: {
                    layout: '/views/home.html'
                },
                title: 'Welcome!'

            })
            .when('/launchpad', {
                templates: {
                    layout: '/views/layouts/default.html',
                    content: '/views/partials/profile.html'
                },
                title: "Launchpad"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });

    }
]);
```

**Other things I have done:**

- In my `index.html`, I already have the `<base href="/">`
- upgraded to angular 1.2.1

**Here are the htaccess rules I have tried. None work.**

from [Refreshing page gives "Page not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168836/refreshing-page-gives-page-not-found)

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|html|png) #Add extra extensions needed.
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

from http://ericduran.io/2013/05/31/angular-html5Mode-with-yeoman/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.html/#!/$1 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have your tried `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.html#!/$1 [L]` (The dot is an reserved char so should escape it)?
And are you sure that `mod_rewrite` works? It's hard to judge where the error is so I would check everything.

Comment: Yes, I later found `hashPrefix` to be part of a working combination (see answer). I believe `mod_rewrite` was working because I was able to get log output from it: (using the block `<IfModule mod_rewrite> RewriteEngine On RewriteLog MY_LOG_PATH RewriteLogLevel 3 </IfModule>`). And I tried the RewriteRule along with the two RewriteCond (`!-f` and `!-d`) but it did not work for me.

Comment: Hey did you find any solution?? I am able to refresh in hashbang mode but in html5 mode it still showing Object not found let me know if you have any solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is the optimal solution, but I did find a combination of settings that worked:

- Include the `hashPrefix('!')` (see below)
- Did not include `<base href="/">` in my index.html
- Added `FallbackResource /index.html` to my `<Directory PATH_TO_WWW_FILES>` section in my server `.conf` file per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16370940/858275). After setting this, it didn't seem to matter what the local `mod_rewrite` settings were.

```js
// Routing configuration.
angular.module('myModule')
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        // Enable pushState in routes.
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templates: {
                    layout: '/views/home.html'
                },
                title: 'Welcome!'

            })
            .when('/launchpad', {
                templates: {
                    layout: '/views/layouts/default.html',
                    content: '/views/partials/profile.html'
                },
                title: "Launchpad"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });

    }
]);
```

Answer (score 8):

This .htaccess setting worked well for me

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
    RewriteRule (.*) /#!/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who are still facing this error, with or without SSL:

Make sure you Allowoverride in your apacheconfig e.g.

```
<Directory "/var/www/mysite/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

for both ports is u use SSL

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't comment but as well as using `HTML mode`, `base href="/"`, `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, using `.htaccess` rewrite. From Unispaw, I had to `AllowOverride All` in **both** the sites available of your site **and** the `/etc/apache2 apache.conf`