# multiple htaccess rewrite Conditions / angular routes html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a angular project with routes in html5 mode. I set up a htaccess file, that is possible to insert a domain manually or refresh the page.

here the htaccess code with works fine, based on this
[Still getting 'Not Found' when manually refreshing with angular.js route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145068/still-getting-not-found-when-manually-refreshing-with-angular-js-route)

```
    RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteRule ^ myFolder/myFile.php [L]
```

but now i want also to redirect the url to https width www, for example:

http://example.com should become https://www.example.com

there for i used this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But when i try to combine this scripts i always get error!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're trying to combine the code, but you should be able to do it this way. Replace `example.com` with *your* domain.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteRule ^ myFolder/myFile.php [L]
```

Clear your browser cache before trying the new rules.