# Why doesn't beforeunload fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, event-handling

I have read lots of other related posts, but cannot understand what's wrong with the following code:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
    debugger
    handleBeforeUnload();
    return false;
});
function handleBeforeUnload() {
    if (location.pathname != "/") {
        location.assign(location.hostname + "/#" + location.pathname);
    }
}
```

I have also tried a pure JavaScript approach without success. The underlying problem I am trying to solve is with angular "pretty" URLs. Although clicking links work fine, when reloading a page (ex. mydomain.com/about) I get a 404 Not Found error. I found that manually inserting a hashbang (mydomain/#/about) works correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Although it is a similar question, it did not give a specific answer for my platform (Apache)

Comment: You didn't ask a specific question for your platform...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168836/refreshing-page-gives-page-not-found, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411206/multiple-htaccess-rewrite-conditions-angular-routes-html5-mode

Comment: Thanks, but neither of those solutions work for me.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here

Your whole higher level problem stems from not configuring server to always serve the app entry point when you are using `html5Mode` pretty URL's

Server has no knowledge of the virtual directories that the client side app uses unless you configure it

Comment: How would you configure it using .htaccess (Apache)?

Comment: Yes that is one way without accessing  config files directly

Comment: Unfortunately, the beforeunload doesn't fire reliably. I wold prefer a server-side solution.

Comment: you can't force user to go to unexpected places using `beforeunload`. Browser won't let you