# Angular app served from Apache

Tags: angularjs, apache

I have an **Angular app** that uses PHP for the API and a little bit for the frontend as well.

**Routing** has become impossible; only 1st level routes are returned.

My structure is as follows:

- /app/index.html
- /app/scripts/[all angular files]
- /app/views/[all PHP-parsed HTML files]
- /app/api/[app PHP files]

Router (Angular):

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider
    .when('/', {redirectTo: '/home'})
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/mainview.php?sec=home',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/user', {
        templateUrl: 'views/mainview.php?sec=user',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
    });
```

vhosts Apache file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
  DocumentRoot "M:/site/app"
  # names and emails commented out
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/user/([0-9]+)$ /user?user=$1
</IfModule>
```

When I access 127.0.0.2, it redirects to /home and works fine.
When I access /user?id=1, it also works fine.
But if I retrieve /user/1, then only the main php-parsed HTML loads, but all dependencies (scripts, css, whatever else) just return the same main HTML file, thus failing.

I have seen [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15284038/2173380) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15385659/2173380) [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24469005/2173380) and so far I have not been able to fix anything...

Can anyone help me make routing happen?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you have a route for /user/1.  Try something like

```
.when('/user/:userId')
```

Check out the example in angular's documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Comment: Indeed i don't. I just expect Apache to translate my /user/1 to /user?id=1 and Angular will take care of that

Comment: My mistake, I see what you're asking now.  Is there a reason you need to add this at the Apache httpd level?  You could setup multiple angular routes to use the same handler.  Good luck.

Comment: AFAIK Apache tries to take care of any route that is deeper than 1 level before Angular can handle it. So That /user works, but /user/1 does not. Or at least that is what seems to happen here. That is why I have to tell Apache to translate routes to 1 level depth. Either that or just tell Apache to NOT HANDLE any route in the vhost.