# Why do we need mod_rewrite module when using AngularJS with Apache 2?

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get AngularJS to work with Apache 2 HTTP Server.  I am finding resources online that suggest changing .htaccess to use the mod_rewrite module(< [rewrite rules for apache 2 to use with angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284038/rewrite-rules-for-apache-2-to-use-with-angular-js) > and < [Apache rewrite rules not being applied for angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385659/apache-rewrite-rules-not-being-applied-for-angularjs/15415902) >).

The answer probably lies in the theory of how Angular and Apache work, but why is a module used for URL rewriting(mod_rewrite) needed in order for Angular to work on Apache?  I thought that Angular was a JavaScript framework and that JavaScript ran on the client.  Even if the HTML page containing Angular needs to be translated before it is served up to the client, what part does a URL rewriting module play in this translation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL rewrite is not needed in every case(as was the case with me).  My problem was that I was using IE and it was starting in compatability mode.

Used the line specified at < [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e) > in my HTML and it worked for me.