# How to remove hash(#) from URL with AngularJS on Apache server?

Tags: angularjs, apache

I am trying to remove hash (`#`) from my url for this I did following steps

#### Config file

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

#### index file

```
<base href="/" />
```

#### `.htaccess` file

```
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

After did all that my single routes like `localhost/login` is working but nested ui-routes are not like `localhost/home/contact`.

Another this if I direct hit localhost its show blank page.

All working fine with `#`.

Comment: I think you need to redirect to your hashed urls: Redirect 301 "/url" "/#!/url" this should still display as the unhashed urls in your browser

Comment: with ui-router there are **no such things as nested views** if you are using `html5mode`. A solution - design your website without nested views, or implement them manually (_without changes in URL_)

Comment: Have you tries this in your config file? $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

Comment: There are several suggested answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15385659/548997) question.

Comment: @saumil_jariwala yes I did.