# Angular Routing Issues

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to set up basic angular routing with a Firebase app and am having difficulty

My index.html is:

```
<html ng-app="SampleApp">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.3/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar>My Navbar</nav>

<div ng-view></div>


</body>
</html>
```

My views/main.html is

```
<div>Main.html</div>
```

My dependencies are

```
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

My config is

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/app/doctors', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'SampleCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

})
```

I should also add that the folder structure is

```
project
  app
   views
     main.html
   app.js
   index.html
```

Whenever I try to hit

```
localhost:8000/app/doctors I get a 404 Error.
```

If I go to localhost:8000/app I am redirected to localhost:8000. If I go to localhost:8000 I see the directory structure and can click app to go index.html and the route is rewritten as localhost:8000

I've also tried localhost:8000/#/app/doctors and no luck there

Comment: Is the unclosed `<html` tag at the top just a typo on here, or is that in your code as well?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: have you included ngRoute in your app dependencies?

Comment: @JaredReeves 1..3.0-beta.17

Comment: @materik yes, updated question to clarify

Comment: Can you post your directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Webserver is trying to serve localhost:8000/app/doctors and not giving the app a chance to serve a page.

Try configuring your webserver so that all requests get routed to the page your app lives on.

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem. AngularJS doesn't run until the whole page is downloaded to your browser. Your server needs to handle the same routes as your client. In a typical example project you'll set up some sort of global '*' handler to go to your home page and let AngularJS deal with the in-app routing from there. For example, in Express this would be something like `app.get('*', pages.index);`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have configured [your routes](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) to [use html5mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting), you need to include a hashbang in the URLs like so (based on your example above):

```
localhost:8000#!/app/doctors
```

If you have configured your routes to use html5mode, then you need to set up URL rewrites on your server. [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284038/rewrite-rules-for-apache-2-to-use-with-angular-js), [firebase hosting](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html)