# Angular 4 on Apache in Subfolder

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

Hiii guys,

my problem is the following:

At the beginning I just had one Angular-App, so I put it into the root folder of my Apache Server. My 404-Redirect on Apache to index.html was working fine.

Now i have two Angular-Apps with the following structure:

---

**Root**

**--> App1 (has its own index.html)**

**--> App2 (has its own index.html)**

---

If i know enter an invalid URL for App1 ( example.com/App1/invalidRoute/ ) my Apache Webserver is redirecting to the root folder.

In this case I want Apache to redirect to " example.com/App1/index.html ".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this StackOverflow question:
[rewrite rules for apache 2 to use with angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284038/rewrite-rules-for-apache-2-to-use-with-angular-js)

The same applies with Angular, and you may need to set a matching basepath in your app if you are not using hash-urls.