# Making Apache2 loading index.html regardless which file the user targets

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

At the moment if I access my https://domain.tld it shows my index.html.

Now I want that regardless what file is accessed it should always load index.html .

So if you type in https://domain.tld/hellostackoverflow it should display index.html but not redirect since it would change the url.

Every answer to similar questions on stackoverflow suggests redirecting everything to index.html but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: This sounds like the problem with routing in angular apps. For which there are lots of answers already on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284038/rewrite-rules-for-apache-2-to-use-with-angular-js

Comment: What has my question to do with a javascript framework?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want the page to change but the URL to remain the same. There is a similar case which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain)