# Enabling HTML5 navigation in Angular 9 Application

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a singlepage application build with Angular 9 and I would like to use urls withoug a hashtag to navigate.

I enabled pushState / HTML5 mode by defining useHash

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: false})
```

and in the index.html the "base entry:

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />
```

so far everything looks ok, but i see, that when requesting a site directly:
instead of:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/upload?transactionId=100603804
```

using

```
http://localhost:4200/upload?transactionId=100603804
```

the whole angular application is reloaded again from the server.
How could it be arranged, that i can use the links without '#' and also to avoid the reloading?

best regards

shane

Comment: When doing that, some configuration is necessary on your server because you are requesting a resource that does not really exist (`/upload`). A rewrite rule must be written so that the server will understand that it should actually serve `index.html`

Comment: The following answer is about angularJs but the logic is the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284038/rewrite-rules-for-apache-2-to-use-with-angular-js

Comment: I thought that modern browsers do not reload the whole application. Isn't it that he HashLocationStrategy is only needed to support older browsers?

Comment: What do you mean by `the whole angular application is reloaded again from the server` ? If you type that in the url and press enter, of course it will reload the whole application. But if place a button that triggers `router.navigate()`, it will just navigate without whole reloading