# Apache2 Angular11 app does not route to new page

Tags: angular, apache, apache2

I have made an Angular app which I'm running on a apache2 server. Everything runs well locally but in apache I'm stuck on the "root/login" page. I'm seeing that it send a request to the backend to login but it does not get routed to the "home" page. I've used a # hash in the URL since I've read that this would fix the issue. I have also tried to activate the symlinks in apache sites enables config but no luck.

I use ng build --prod to build the app and paste the files from the dist folder to var/www/html for apache. The login page gets rendered well but it does not go to the home page. It just stays on the login page and I get no errors.

My angular routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './components/welcome/welcome.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/welcome/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/welcome/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My apache2 000-degault.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    
    # redirect 404 to index page
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    #RewriteEngine on
    
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    
    <Directory /var/www/html>
    options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there something I need to fix in Apache or Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to activate RewriteEngine up there in your config.

You can find some information about some config options you might need for example here: [rewrite rules for apache 2 to use with angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284038/rewrite-rules-for-apache-2-to-use-with-angular-js)