# URL with trailing slash from AngularJs/ui-router to nginx accesses incorrect resource

Tags: angularjs, http, nginx, angular-ui-router

I have an `AngularJs` app (with routing by `ui-router`) being served by `nginx`.

I'm not sure exactly who/what the culprit is, but when I **refresh** my browser with a URL with a **trailing slash**, it looks like the latter part of the URL is treated as a *subdirectory*, and static resources (`img` / `css` / `js` / etc) are then requested from a location **prefixed with this subdirectory** (which doesn't exist)

**Example:**

- rereshing `www.site.com/login` will require `logo.png`, which will be requested from `www.site.com/images/logo.png`
- rereshing `www.site.com/login/` **(trailing slash)** will require `logo.png`, which will be requested from `www.site.com/`**`login`**`/images/logo.png`

I need to somehow prevent this `login/` as being treated as a subdirectory.

**nginx config:**

Since angular does its own routing, in my `nginx` config I have an *api route* for the REST api, and a *fallback route* for all other URIs, which serves `index.html` for all unknown resources.

I have added config to strip trailing slashes from URIs.

```
# api route
location ~* /api.? {
    ...
}

# fallback route
location ~* .? {
    # strip any trailing slash
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 break;

    root /var/www/site/app;
    index index.html;

    # serve index.html if uri doesn't exist
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Whenever I try to refresh a route with a trailing slash, it looks as if something (Angular/nginx/browser?) treats the URI as a directory, and **prefixes that directory** onto all the GET requests for static resources, which breaks.

*Here are excerpts from my nginx log:*

**Works: refresh an angular route with no trailing slash**

`http://localhost/login`

```
[debug] : http request line: "GET /login HTTP/1.1"
[debug] : http header: "Referer: http://localhost/"
[debug] : http request line: "GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1"
```

**Doesn't Work: refresh an angular route with a trailing slash**

`http://localhost/login/`

```
[debug] : http request line: "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1"
[debug] : http header: "Referer: http://localhost/login/"
[debug] : http request line: "GET /login/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 

*error* /login/images/logo.png doesn't exist
```

I'm not sure if the `Referer` header is a red-herring?

**Question**

How can I configure `angular` and/or `ui-router` and/or `ngingx` (or whoever the culprit is) so that refreshing routes with trailing slashes works?

Comment: I do assume you are using push state in angular and this is why you get real paths like `/bla/login/page` instead of `/#/bla/login/page` so in this case easiest fix is not to use the push state as it requires server config to work for every path.
More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095179/using-html5-pushstate-on-angular-js

Comment: @ivarPrudnikov - thanks for the comment, and you are correct - but that is why I have the `try_files` serving `/index.html` - so that if the resource pointed to by `$uri` doesn't exist, it will fall back to serving `/index.html`... this is not the cause of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by setting the base to root

```
    <base href="/">
```

Comment: for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768814/angularjs-routing-set-base-url-for-all-routes