# HTML5 pushState Clash w/Angular UI-Router URL Routing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, pushstate

I have an Angular.js webapp that employs ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) w/parallel named views like such:

```
.state(
            'app.experience', {
                url: 'e/:experienceId',
                views: {
                    'center-pane@': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/experience.html',
                        controller: 'ExperienceController'
                    }
                })
```

I enabled HTML5 pushState via

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

When

```
http://www.mysite.com/e/123
```

is requested, my backend sends back the index.html at the root directory. (as per [Using HTML5 pushstate on angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095179/using-html5-pushstate-on-angular-js)) However, when the browser receives index.html and begins to fetch all the css/js resources, the requests are for

```
/e/js/script1.js
```

as opposed to

```
/js/script1.js
```

which only exists at the root level. It seems to default the root directory as `mysite.com/e/` (from the requested url) and not the actual root, `mysite.com/`.

Is there something I'm missing here? Is it not possible to use relative srcs for my javascript and css in index.html?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: You haven't shown us your how HTML looks but based on your issue I'm going to assume that you are **not** using relative urls from the document root.

You can use relative urls but they should be relative *based on the document root*.

So for example, you might have something like this in your html

```
<img src="images/foo.jpg" />
```

You should really do it this way (notice the addition of the beginning '/' slash)

```
<img src="/images/foo.jpg" />
```

This isn't something specific to angularjs, it's an html thing, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/238427) for more details.

The reason why your browser is using the `/e/` in the url is because the **the browser** actually requested a resource that has the `/e/` in the url. The browser doesn't know that your server responded with a file that is not in the `/e/` directory.

Therefore, if you have a relative url without a forward slash in the beginning, it will be relative to the path or the original requested resource.  What you want is to use relative urls with a slash in the beginning.

Comment: Yup this was it. Thanks for the help!