# Changing url in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When creating a single page web app, the url should never change. I've done this with jQuery and simply load html content from the backend server when the user clicks on a link.

How is this done using AngularJS? Many of the tutorials I've come across indicate that the browser's url changes causing a route provider to load dynamic content. But the browser's url should not change, so I'm kind of confused on how AngularJS is suppose to get dynamic html from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seaching for is **ngRoute**.

I suppose there is no need for me to copy-paste the examples here.

[Official docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route)

On the bottom of the page you also have an example.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS works with a client side router.
that means that the route does change, but browser navigation isn't triggered (you will not experience a "refresh").

Angular manages state-machine (or routes) and views, and manages the transition between them automatically.

check out Angular's documentation for ngRoute:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: The example shows the <a> tag being used as link where the user clicks on it and AngularJS intercepts this and then uses routing to retrieve the partial content from the backend. What other means can we use other than <a> tags to initiate the navigation? Any javascript functions or AngularJS functions?

Comment: In case of ngRoute, angular makes the $location service available for injection anywhere in your application, and you can navigate to any state/route you've pre-configured.
as for ui-router, the $state service has a .go() method that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

> When creating a single page web app, the url should never change.

I don't really understand that completely. You probably mean that they shouldn't be a full page reload. However, they are two ways to change the URL in a Angular JS App:

Yes, [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route) is the way to go.

## Using hash

The most easy to implement method is the hash (eg what is after the `#` symbol in the URL bar).

## Using the pushState HTML5 API

They is a question about exactly this here: [using html5 pushstate on angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095179/using-html5-pushstate-on-angular-js)

Comment: None of the single page apps I've created ever changed the url in the browser to load partial data. I used Ajax to dynamically download content and display it. The browser's url never changes but the url to the dynamic content does.

Comment: Well I think it's a better practice to let the URL change: for history support first, and also linkability. I can't think of an easy way to load data without changing the URL in angular, except creating your own system